# Storing multiple parameters into one variable Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, function, variables, oracle11g

I am working on an assignment. What I want to do is store two parameter values into one variable value. My code at the moment is this:

```
create or replace function generateISIN(
  countryCode Country.Code%type,
  universityCode University.Code%type,
  studentNumber varchar2)
return varchar2
as
  v_numbers varchar2(9);
  newStudentNumber varchar2(50) := '';
begin
  select co.code, un.code
  into newStudentNumber
  from country co, university un
  where v_numbers = studentNumber;
  dbms_output.put_line('implementeer deze functie verder...');
  return newStudentNumber;
end;
/
```

The meaning of this program/code is to get the country code (US, NL, AUS, etc..) and the university code (RUS, TUE, TIU, etc..) into one variable. So in the end I will get a ISIN

> International Student Identification Number

For example: `NL 1234 5678 944 TUE`

Any idea how to combine the country code and university code with a number?

Comment: On second glance (after posting an answer), your SELECT looks strange - why do you use the local variable v_numbers in your WHERE condition? And where is your JOIN condition for country and university?

Comment: I am new to PL / SQL. So I don't always have a clue what to do. In the end I want to add the country and university code to the variable 'newStudentNumber'. You got any clue how to do it? or how far am I off :)

Comment: Assuming you want a row for each student in your result set, I'd expect another JOIN with a `student` table. Also, I'd expect a JOIN condition that links universities to their countries - as it currently stands, your query performs a full cartesian join between both tables. I'd recommend you run the query standalone (not as part of a PL/SQL package) and check the results. Also, I'd recommend you use ANSI style joins instead of old-style ones (rule of thumb: your FROM clause should mention only one table). If you need further assistance, please ask a separate question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your variable is big enough to hold the result, you can simply concatenate the columns using the string concatenation operator `||`:

```
select co.code || un.code
  into newStudentNumber
  from country co, university un
  where v_numbers = studentNumber;
```

Comment: Yep. That did the trick. Thanks alot! I marked your awnser as the right given awnser

Answer (score 1):

You could simply **concatenate** the column values using the concatenate operator `||` or the **CONCAT** function.

For example,

```
select co.code ||' '|| un.code
  into newStudentNumber
  from country co, university un
  where v_numbers = studentNumber;
```

I have used a space in between just to make sure that the output is clear and each code is separated by a space.

**Update** You need to correct your query:

> ```
> select co.code, un.code
>   into newStudentNumber
>   from country co, university un
>   where v_numbers = studentNumber;
> ```

- You have a Cartesian join since the filter predicate has no real column(s)
- On both sides of the operator you have used the local variable, makes no sense. Usually, you would do a comparison in a `IF-ELSE` construct based on the business logic.

> dbms_output.put_line('implementeer deze functie verder...');

**DBMS_OUTPUT** is a good help while testing your code, however, make sure you don't carry it on **production environment**.

Also, remember, if you could do something in SQL, then you should not use PL/SQL unless there is a business need. Your entire code could be replaced with a single SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Frank Schmitt was a little bit earlier with the awnser, but thanks anyway. I upvoted your awnser aswell

Comment: No problem. But make sure you use my solution as the column values needs to be separated by a space, else you would see both values together.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that

Comment: There are other issues with your PL/SQL code, please see my updated answer.